# Docker container giving 404 on every request

Tags: flask, dockerfile, flask-restful, docker-container, docker-image

I am dockerizing a Flask app and the docker container is working perfectly but when I try to hit the APIs I get 404 on every request.

**This is my docker file**

`FROM python:3.11-slim`

`WORKDIR /app`

`COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt`

`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

`COPY . .`

`CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`
`` ` ``

**This is my run file**

`"""module imports""" from api import app if __name__ == "__main__":     app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=False)  # add host='----`

**docker build command:**
`docker build -t my-image .`

**docker run command:**
`docker container run --env-file .env -it  -d -p   5000:5000 my-image`

I have already checked the available solutions to this problem but none of them seems to solve it.

Comment: Does it work https://arshovon.com/blog/develop-flask-app-using-docker-and-bootstrap/?